# JSON Request adjusting URL params

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to request data from a URL dependant on the lat/lng searched for. this is my method so far but I am having problems with building the URL with the search params;

```
 double latitude = extras.getDouble("latitude");
double longitude = extras.getDouble("longitude");
```

This is lat lng from prev activity

This is my maps activity method where I will be fetching data I have not made the request yet as I want to get the URL right first

```
 public void getApiData() {
    // CMPTODO: build URI


    /**
     * built a URL with the lat/lng passed from prev activity
     */

    String lat = String.valueOf(latitude);
    String lng = String.valueOf(longitude);
    Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(API_URL).buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter("lat", lat)
            .appendQueryParameter("lng", lng)
            .build();

        URL urlApi = new URL(builtUri.toString());


        //TODO: fetch API data
        // TODO: Search prefs adjust lat and long to address in JSON URL.


    if (URLUtil.isValidUrl(builtUri)){

    }else {

    }

    }


}
```

[image: ERROR]

SideNote I am new to Android Dev so I could be going about this the wrong way. any advice is welcomed

URL

```
        public static final String API_URL= "https://data.police.uk/api/crimes-at-location?date=2017-02&lat=52.629729&lng=-1.131592";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Using [OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp) library.

> ```
> implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
> ```

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();

final Request.Builder builder = new Request.Builder();

HttpUrl.Builder urlBuilder = HttpUrl.parse(url).newBuilder();
urlBuilder.addEncodedQueryParameter("lat", lat)
urlBuilder.addEncodedQueryParameter("lng", lng)

builder.url(urlBuilder.build().toString());

client.newCall(builder.build())
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap `new URL(builtUri.toString());` inside **`try - catch`** block because `new URL(builtUri.toString());` may throw  [**`MalformedURLException`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/MalformedURLException)

> **`MalformedURLException`**
>   Thrown to indicate that a malformed URL has occurred. Either no legal protocol could be found in a specification string or the string could not be parsed.

Try this

```
   URL urlApi;
    try {
        urlApi = new URL(builtUri.toString());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Follow the following steps

```
String URL = YOUR_API_URL;

Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse(URL).buildUpon();

builder.appendQueryParameter("value", your_value);

URL=builder.build().toString();
```